# Set raw values in Google Sheets through App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The behaviour of Google Sheets App Script `Range.setValues` function seems to be tied to the number format of the cell to be modified:

- If you set *Format->Number->Automatic*, it will try to parse numeric strings as numbers.
- If you set *Format->Number->Plain text*, it will coerce boolean `false` to string `"false"`.

What I'd much enjoy is a sensible behaviour similar to Google Sheets API v4, where you can [force it to interpret values as raw.](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption)

What I am looking for is unambiguous behaviour, where javascript

- string `""` stays string.
- number `1.23` stays number.
- boolean `true` stays boolean.
- Date `Date(...)` stays date.

Does anyone know whether something like that is possible?

Comment: If you need raw entry à la Sheets API, then use the Sheets API? It is available in Apps Script.

Comment: Could you elaborate little bit more? Is it possible to use Sheets API directly from script associated with that Sheet without a need to create service worker, sending requests through REST, etc...?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets#write_values_to_multiple_ranges

Comment: Thank you! It sounds like the right solution @tehhowch. I will happily accept it as a right answer if you write it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround for when you have *Format->Number->Automatic*.

```js
function sanitizeData(data) {
  return data.map(function(row) {
    return row.map(function(value) {
      return typeof value === 'string' ? "'" + value : value;
    });
  });
}
```

This will fail if the Number Format is explicitly set to *Plain Text*. However, you can clear the formatting using the [`clear(options)` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear(Object)).

Comment: I am not happy with this answer, so, if anyone has better idea, he/she is more than welcome.